# Update / delete multiple objects using Jongo

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I have a method which takes in a Collection of Objects that are to be deleted.

This is the way I am deleting them now

```
public void deleteAll(Collection<Object> objs){
     for(Object obj : objs) {
       collection.remove("{ _id: # }", obj.getId());
     }
}
```

I am doing something very similar for update where I am looping through the passed collection of Objects. This seems to be very time consuming.

Is there a better way of doing the update/delete?

Comment: The basic concept even though I am not familiar with the syntax in this library is using the **`$in`** operator with a list. So if you can somehow "map" out all your `_id` values into a list type then you should be able to send as an argument using that operator. I see there is a section on "Query Templating" under the [Query](http://jongo.org/#querying) examples on the main site that might apply to this.

Comment: Thanks Neil, that helped a lot with the deletes. With updates though, I am able to extract out all the documents that need to be updated, but I am still not sure how to save all the new documents in one go. The with() and save() methods of Jongo accept only 1 Object at a time and do not accept a collection of Objects

Comment: As I have said before I don't really have any experience with Jongo and also a lack of time to try out some examples, but if you have a MongoDB 2.6 or greater version then this manual section on [Bulk Update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/#bulk-update) may be of interest. I have posted a few answers on the usage, and there should be a way for you to at least get to the raw database object from the Java driver in order to use the required `runCommand` version of this. Or possibly other bulk update API exposed by your Java driver if it is a recent release.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to both remove and update multiple documents with a single query.

**remove**

You need to use a query with a selector using `$in`, and an array of `_id` values to match.

With Jongo, you can build the list to match with `$in` into the query in a couple of different ways

```
// pass an array of ids
ObjectId[] ids = {id1, id2, id3};
collection.remove("{ _id: { $in: # } }", ids);

// or pass each id separately
collection.remove("{ _id: { $in:[#, #, #] }}", id1, id2, id3);
```

**update**

Exact same concept as above using `$in` to select the objects you want to update, however **you also have to set the** `multi` **option**, so that the update applies to all the documents it matches against, not just the first.

With Jongo this is done like so

```
ObjectId[] ids = {id1, id2, id3};
collection
  .update("{ _id: { $in: # } }", ids)
  .multi()
  .with({ $set: { foo: "bar" });
```